# Symfony2 entity field type: translate list items

Tags: forms, symfony, translation

I have a Symfony2 form with an entity field type with country codes. Now I want to translate each item of the field to show the name of the language in the language of the current users locale.

How can I translate the items?

```
         ->add('country', 'entity', array(
            'required'          => true,
            'property'          => 'countrycodeiso3166',
            'class'             => 'xxxDatabaseBundle:Country',
            'query_builder'     => function (EntityRepository $er) {
                return $er->createQueryBuilder('c')
                    ->orderBy('c.countrycodeiso3166', 'ASC');
            },
        ))
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Where do you have stored entity name translated?

Comment: To store any translation of language codes should not be required because symfony/php provides the Intl-Package - but how can I use it?

Comment: Wait, I can't understand you. What do you need? A list with all languages in the current language? Am I right?

Comment: Yes, you're right. I need this list, but the selected language must be a entity, because I need the relation from the entity I save to the language (1:1 relation). And I would like to know how I can translate the items of the field type/widget.

Comment: So, just to be more clear, you are storing every single language into a table (entity)?

Comment: Not the language, the country ;-) But, yes..

Comment: Ok, so how do you expect symfony2 do it itself? :)

Comment: It's a project requirement... ;)

Comment: No, wait, you can reach that goal, but Intl-Package as nothing to do with this. Usually I tackle the problem in that way: I create a table with all translations that I need and i use a data transformer to show translated entities. Don't know if is the best approach, but this works

Answer (score 1):

According to the [docs](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/translation.html#translating-database-content) the translation of database content should be handled by Doctrine through the Translatable Extension or the Translatable Behavior.

But you could also manually store the translations of the items within the entity itself, e.g. as an associative array. Then you can make use of the [PropertyAccessor](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/property_access/introduction.html) functionality of the [choice_label](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/entity.html#choice-label) option (formerly known as property option).

Another way would be to fall back to the choice field type, which has [extended choice_label features](http://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-2-7-choice-form-type-refactorization) since symfony 2.7. Then you could modify the choice_label to fit the translation representation of each country code in your translation files (e.g. messages.de.yml).

EDIT: I just saw that the entity field type supports the extended choice_label features as well. So you could do something easy like this (assuming you have an appropriate getter for countrycodeiso3166)

```
->add('country', 'entity', array(
        'required'          => true,
        'choice_label'      => function ($entity) { return \Symfony\Component\Intl\Intl::getLanguageBundle()->getLanguageName($entity->getCountrycodeiso3166()); },
        'class'             => 'xxxDatabaseBundle:Country',
        'query_builder'     => function (EntityRepository $er) {
            return $er->createQueryBuilder('c')
                ->orderBy('c.countrycodeiso3166', 'ASC');
        },
    ))
```

Answer (score 0):

It may help to use Symfony's [language](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/language.html) field type which is designed especially for this task.

Comment: That's an solution for the problem, but not the answer of my question ;-)